# what's the keyboard shortcut in a PC to select multiple nodes in FreeMind?

Tags: freemind

what's the keyboard shortcut in a PC to select multiple nodes in FreeMind?

to select multiple nodes, press Ctrl and click the left mouse button, but i don't know how to select by shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the node you want to start with using the **cursor keys**.
- Hold down **shift**, and use the **cursor keys** to select other nodes as
  necessary.